# How to password protect an uploaded PDF in PHP

Tags: php, security, passwords

I have a web application where users can upload PDF documents. Is there a PHP library that I can use to password protect the PDF file? I need the library to preserve all aspects of the original PDF (i.e. size, fonts, resolution, etc).

Comment: Do you want to password protect the file itself, or only when you try and open it from within your web app?

Answer (score 8):

[Download the library used: Protect PDF in PHP](http://www.idsecuritysuite.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/fpdi.zip)

```
<?php

function pdfEncrypt ($origFile, $password, $destFile){
//include the FPDI protection http://www.setasign.de/products/pdf-php-solutions/fpdi-protection-128/
require_once('fpdi/FPDI_Protection.php');

$pdf =& new FPDI_Protection();
// set the format of the destinaton file, in our case 6×9 inch
$pdf->FPDF('P', 'in', array('6','9'));

//calculate the number of pages from the original document
$pagecount = $pdf->setSourceFile($origFile);

// copy all pages from the old unprotected pdf in the new one
for ($loop = 1; $loop <= $pagecount; $loop++) {
    $tplidx = $pdf->importPage($loop);
    $pdf->addPage();
    $pdf->useTemplate($tplidx);
}

// protect the new pdf file, and allow no printing, copy etc and leave only reading allowed
$pdf->SetProtection(array(),$password);
$pdf->Output($destFile, 'F');

return $destFile;
}

//password for the pdf file
$password = 'info@domain.com';

//name of the original file (unprotected)
$origFile = 'book.pdf';

//name of the destination file (password protected and printing rights removed)
$destFile ='book_protected.pdf';

//encrypt the book and create the protected file
pdfEncrypt($origFile, $password, $destFile );
?>
```

**EDIT**
[Original source of library used](https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/downloads/). Please note that my answer above was not tested using the script from the original source. I downloaded from the third party link above and I didn't check if they're exactly the same.

Comment: Please specify the source from where you downloaded the library. That page would be of more help that direct link to the library.

Comment: @mccbala See my edit. Remember to +1 question and answer if you found this useful.

Comment: When i try with any existing PDF file it will give error "This document probably uses a compression technique which is not supported by the free parser shipped with FPDI. (See https://www.setasign.com/fpdi-pdf-parser for more details)"

Comment: In a Laravel or any other app that uses namespaces and a bootloader, an option may be using FPDI with TCPDF. Docs at https://github.com/Setasign/FPDI. It allows you to use SetProtection() method from TCPDF