# How to password protect pdf in PHP

Tags: php, security, password-protection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to password protect an uploaded pdf in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12700974/how-to-password-protect-an-uploaded-pdf-in-php)

I have a web app where users can upload pdf documents. Is there a php library that I can use to password protect the pdf file? I need the library to preserve all aspects of the original pdf (i.e. size, fonts, resolution, etc).

Comment: Do you wanna password-protect just the web-access to the file or the actual file?

Comment: First google result for "How to password protect pdf in PHP": http://www.idsecuritysuite.com/blog/password-protect-a-pdf-document-in-php

Comment: I want to password the file itself.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Download the library used: Protect PDF in PHP](http://www.idsecuritysuite.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/fpdi.zip)

```
<?php

function pdfEncrypt ($origFile, $password, $destFile){
//include the FPDI protection http://www.setasign.de/products/pdf-php-solutions/fpdi-protection-128/
require_once('fpdi/FPDI_Protection.php');

$pdf =& new FPDI_Protection();
// set the format of the destinaton file, in our case 6×9 inch
$pdf->FPDF('P', 'in', array('6','9'));

//calculate the number of pages from the original document
$pagecount = $pdf->setSourceFile($origFile);

// copy all pages from the old unprotected pdf in the new one
for ($loop = 1; $loop <= $pagecount; $loop++) {
    $tplidx = $pdf->importPage($loop);
    $pdf->addPage();
    $pdf->useTemplate($tplidx);
}

// protect the new pdf file, and allow no printing, copy etc and leave only reading allowed
$pdf->SetProtection(array(),$password);
$pdf->Output($destFile, 'F');

return $destFile;
}

//password for the pdf file
$password = 'info@domain.com';

//name of the original file (unprotected)
$origFile = 'book.pdf';

//name of the destination file (password protected and printing rights removed)
$destFile ='book_protected.pdf';

//encrypt the book and create the protected file
pdfEncrypt($origFile, $password, $destFile );
?>
```

Comment: And if I want to programmatically re-open the encrypted file with FPDF? Is it possible?

Comment: How could we protect pdf file from binary string and not form real file? And generate pdf on php page by using resulted string and: header("Content-type:application/pdf;"); Thanks!!