# Laravel add password protection for existing PDF file

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, password-protection

I'm using Laravel 5.4 and PHP 7.0. I want to add password protection for existing PDF file, i searched on the internet but only found solution of adding password protection when export PDF file from HTML to PDF.

Please give me some recommend about library or solution to solve this problem.

Comment: What about wrapping your download-routes with a special middleware? So you can easily grant access to your pdfs to a certain group of users.

Comment: my purpose is attaching pdf file with password protection into Gmail

Comment: What about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12700974/how-to-password-protect-an-uploaded-pdf-in-php

Answer (score 1):

Enter following command :

```
composer require reposys/laravel-pdf
```

To start using Laravel, add the Service Provider and the Facade to your config/app.php:

```
 'providers' => [
// ...
 niklasravnsborg\LaravelPdf\PdfServiceProvider::class
]
'aliases' => [
// ...
'PDF' => niklasravnsborg\LaravelPdf\Facades\Pdf::class
 ]
```

To set protection, you just call the SetProtection() method and pass an array with permissions, an user password and an owner password.

The passwords are optional.

There are a fews permissions: 'copy', 'print', 'modify', 'annot-forms', 'fill-forms', 'extract', 'assemble', 'print-highres'.

```
use PDF;

function generate_pdf() {
 $data = [
    'foo' => 'bar'
];
 $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.document', $data);
 $pdf->SetProtection(['copy', 'print'], '', 'pass');
 return $pdf->stream('document.pdf');
}
```

Comment: PDF::loadView('pdf.document', $data); : this step is loading view from html with data, and export to excel, right?? i want to add password to existing pdf file

Comment: Encrypt the file and grant no permissions to the user.
 The user will need to use "UserPassword" to open the file.
 Owner has full rights using the password "MyPassword".

        $pdf->SetProtection(array(), 'UserPassword', 'MyPassword');

Answer (score 0):

like this

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class DownloadController extents Controller
{
    public function showForm()
    {
        return view('show.password.form'); //add view with form
    }
    public function download(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->input('password') === 'your password') {
            return response()->download($pathToFile);
        } else {
            abort(403, 'Unauthorized action.');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: my purpose is attaching pdf file with password protection into Gmail